# In the ESXi 5 console, how to press the <+> and <-> keys on the bios screens without the num part of the keyboard?

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-vsphere, bios, keyboard

Sometimes we open vSphere from a restricted terminal that only has a basic ascii keyboard and f1-f12 and a mouse but is missing the additional numeric block on the right side of a big keybaord part and also there is no numlock state.

In the bios screen of a vm you have to press num-<+> or num-<-> to move the boot order of devices.

As we don't have these keys, how can we do it?

The <+> and <-> keys on the normal keyboard do not seem to work (although everything else works).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the help screen in the bios (<kbd>F1</kbd>), <kbd>F5</kbd> should act like <kbd>-</kbd> and <kbd>F6</kbd> should act like <kbd>+</kbd>.  Unfortunately, this seems to be a lie - it works in normal item selection, but not in the boot order selection; only <kbd>+</kbd>/<kbd>-</kbd> seem to do anything.

Your only recourse may be to get a keyboard with working <kbd>-</kbd> and <kbd>=</kbd> keys.

Comment: That the keys F5 and F6 do not work at this point was also my observation. ;/